# Set Default Time In Datetime Picker windows form

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have a windows form there  i want that when form load this display 10:00 as Default time in `datetimepicker` . Can you please tell me how can i do this . Below is from there i want to display the time In my Ready Time . [image: Windows Form There i want to display time]

Thanks for you comment and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() + " 10:00 PM");
```

Comment: Error Cannot Convert Type String To 'System.Date.Time' i use this  `TimePickerReadyTime.Value = System.DateTime.Today + " 10:00 PM";`

Comment: Sorry, I had it working in VB.NET first -- had to convert to C#.

Comment: @Abhishek -- Add `dateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;` and `dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "H:mm";`

Comment: thanks for your reply . i use this `TimePickerReadyTime.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom);`
           ` TimePickerReadyTime.CustomFormat = "H:mm";`  and getting error `Invalid cast from 'Enum' to 'DateTime'.`

Comment: That's because `TimePickerReadyTime.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom);` is not correct.  Why are you trying to do that?  You can't convert an enumeration -- i.e. `System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom` -- to a `DateTime`.

Comment: i want to display current time 10:00 when form open and time will be 24 hrs format that will display in timepicker . i want this ?

Comment: Then use just the code I gave you and not the code you suggested.

Comment: means i use 'dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() + " 10:00 PM");' this but problem is it display 10:00:00 PM in time picker but i want 24 hrs format

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about. If you use the three lines of code I gave you then it will work like it did for me.

Comment: First line: `dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() + " 10:00 PM");`

Comment: Second line: `dateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;`

Comment: Third line: `dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "H:mm";`

Comment: its display 22:00 there i want 10:00 in time :(

Comment: Thnks Its works i change " 10:00 PM"); to " 10:00 AM");