# How to set DateTimePicker to specific time?

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I am using windows forms.

I want to set my dateTimePicker to `14:30:00` time when button is clicked.

I already changed the dateTimePicker1 property so it only shows time:

```
dateTimePicker1.Formate = Time
```

I know how to set it to the current time by using: `"dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now"` but how do I set the time to `14:30:00` when button is clicked?

Any idea? thank you

Comment: possibe duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863689/set-default-time-in-datetime-picker-windows-form

Comment: @jLaw this sounds like a dup to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePicker1.Value = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 14, 30, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with

```
dateTimePicker1.Formate = new DateTime(2015, 12, 11, 14, 30, 0)
```

DateTime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec, milli sec)

And if you allways want to get the current day you can do this with that:

```
DateTime s = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(14, 30, 0);
s = s.Date + ts;

Console.WriteLine(s);
```

The output is 11.12.2015 14:30

Comment: Is that what are you searching for ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a new DateTime:

```
DateTime time = new DateTime();
```

And then add the appropriate time to it.

```
time.AddHours(14);
time.AddMinutes(30);
```

Or if you want less code.

```
time.AddMinutes((14*60)+30);
```